# How to insert into SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert

Updated question:

For some reason, I got my code working (must have been a typo or something, still unsure). However, here's the final thing that puzzles me. I have this code:

```
string strConn = @"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database\DbFilm.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";

string insQuery = "INSERT INTO film (naam, medium_id, genre_id, land_id, jaar, lengte, videoformaat_id) VALUES (@naam, @medium_id, @genre_id, @land_id, @jaar, @lengte, @videoformaat_id)";

using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
{
  con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand Query = new SqlCeCommand(insQuery, con))   
    {
     Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", dbNaam);
     Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medium_id", dbMedium_id);
     Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre_id", dbGenre_id);
     Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@land_id", dbLand_id);
     Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jaar", dbJaar);
     Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lengte", dbLengte);
     Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@videoformaat_id", dbVideoformaat_id);

     Query.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
     Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
     {
       con.Close();
     }
   }
```

This does not work. I don't get an error, but my database doesn't receive an insert. When I break at `ExecuteNonQuery`, I notice that the resulting query didn't get the proper values for the `@parameters`. So the actual query looks (in short) something like this:

```
INSERT INTO film (naam, medium_id) VALUES (@naam, @medium_id)
```

But it should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO film (naam, medium_id) VALUES ('title1', 'disc1')
```

What should I do to get the values from the strings (`dbNaam`, `dbMedium_id` and such) in place of `@naam`, `@medium_id` in my query?

P.S. When I use this code with a query that does not use AddWithValue's, it works just fine.

Comment: So... remove the catch and find out what exception you're getting

Comment: Possibly because you are not adding the second parameter?

Comment: I get the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: Sorry, ByteBlast, that was bad copy-pasting. The second parameter is in my original code (edited my question).

Comment: Is the second parameter supposed to be numeric?

Comment: You say that you have simplified the query. What is the real names used in your query? Table name and column names?

Comment: My database has 12 tables, a few of them are very basic, with just an ID (INT) and a name (VARCHAR). I tried with the most basic tables, also without the Add parameters:
"INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES (15, 'abc')"
I have a feeling it's not the query.

Comment: I have asked to know the names of the database objects for a reason. [Take a look at this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173340.aspx). If you have any name listed here you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I actually simplified because my data is in Dutch. I have tried on a table named 'persoon', which consists of two columns: 'id' (PK, autoincrement) and 'eigenaar' (VARCHAR). Then I used the following line of code:
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO persoon (eigenaar) values ('naam')", con))

Comment: If you break when the exception occurs, you should be able to expand it to get a message describing the exception. Can you share what exception message it's reporting?

Comment: Ok, I'm puzzled. I was trying again and suddenly it worked. No idea what it was, so I'll just blame myself, not the code. However, now I'm left with a final problem. My intended query (which is very long) uses the Add parameters. When I break at the ExecuteNonQuery line, I notice that the resulting query doesn't show the actual values, but the '@val' strings. So, "AddWithValue("@val", 'test)" gives a query like 'INSERT INTO ... @val) instead of 'INSERT INTO ... 'test').

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name(column1,column2) VALUES (@Val1,@Val2)", con);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually what I have. It doesn't work. Also, without the Add parameters (...values (123, 'abc') it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but based on your query, I have a feeling the error occurred because of the use of `keyword` in column name.

`name`, `column`, `number` are all SQL keywords. One way to avoid it is to put a `[]` around the column name, for example, `INSERT INTO [column] ([name], [number])`, this will tell the SQL that these are column names instead of trying to invoke a function or something. However, my recommendation is always to avoid using keywords.

Try and let me know if it fixes your error.

Additional tips: Since you're able to get till `ExecuteNonQuery`, set a break point there, and right click and take a look at the actual query being sent to the database. Copy the query and paste it directly in the database and see if it runs.

Comment: I copy-pasted the query from the ExecuteNonQuery breakline directly to the database, where it works. Also tried a different table, named 'lokatie' which has columns 'ruimte' (INT) and 'naam' (VARCHAR). I get query "INSERT INTO lokatie (ruimte, naam) VALUES (1, 'abc')"
Query works directly on the database, but not in my code.